# Best practice for uploading .Net project to Web Server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, publish

What is the best practice to upload .Net project onto the server without disrupting users?

In Visual Studio, there is a Publish button which allows you to upload via FTP. I noticed when you publish, there is a down time (when the critical files like DLL are being overwritten). If something does not work, how do I roll back?

How do I do versioning so I can roll back to a previous implementation?

Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 2):

Publish on your local IIS.

in IIS 7, there is create Package option, create package of your application.
go to your production server, Open IIS 7 console, select your webApplication. Right Click and Go to Restore Package option. it takes less time. make sure the location of package and your application physical path on same drive.

For IIS 6 there is extension available to get that facility. You can find it easily after googling it.

Always keep your code in Source Safe/ or under Team Foundation Server, apply the label before publish, give it a release Name like "1.4.2343" and so. so you can easily identify it. Always apply the label on [previous version + modified files]. Well there are many options :).

Take the back up of existing package before restoring the new one.

**In case of Shared Hosting:**

Notice the time when minimum users are using your application. (This comes after observing your application everyday).

Notify your registered users by email about "Maintenance/ Upgrade Process" few days earlier.

Don't schedule Upgrade too often, this will lower your site's reputation down.

Take the backup your application before uploading.

Set a temporary "Maintinance page" your default application page, using your site management console.

Use any other FTP Client for Uploading.

And....... Start Uploading.

Regards,

Mazhar Karimi

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Mazhar. What if my .Net project is hosted in a Shared Hosting environment and not a VPS? I would not be able to have control over IIS. And I only have Visual Studio 2008. Is source safe the only way to "Version-ize" it?

Comment: i update my post for your problem, and No, source saf/ TFS is not the only options, there are many other popular source controlling software available, also free :)